# CSS - Empty colored container relative to size of parent container

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got a header on my webpage that changes height based on the viewport (eg. 15vh) and has a min-height of 50px.

I'd like to make a colored square within this header that is always exactly 50% of the height of the header regardless of the user's viewport. There will be no content in the colored box. It is for style purposes only. I know that I can't use height: 15%; as there is no content in the container and, as a result, nothing will be displayed. I can't define the box in terms of viewport units because the header isn't always 15% of the height of the viewport (due to the min-height assignment).

Is there any way to accomplish this with CSS?

Here's my setup:

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.header {
  position: relative;
  background-color: grey;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
  min-height: 50px;
}

.responsivecontainer {
  float: left;
  max-width: 20vw;
  min-height: 50px;
  display: flex;
}

.logo {
  margin: auto 0;
}

.clearfix:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.box {
  float: left;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: black;
}

.clearfix {
  display: inline-block;
}


/* Hides from IE-mac \*/

* html .clearfix {
  height: 1%;
}

.clearfix {
  display: block;
}


/* End hide from IE-mac */


/* @end */
```

```html
<div class="header clearfix">

  <div class="responsivecontainer">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="http://www.bluebean.ca/logo1.jpg">
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <img src="http://www.bluebean.ca/grey.jpg">
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample css you already tried?

Comment: And the HTML (and relevant CSS) defining your header. It's not at all clear why you can't use `height: 50%`.

Comment: I've created a code pen to show my problem. I want the grey box to be 50% of the height of the banner at any given time. It doesn't seem to be responsive.    https://codepen.io/jasonhoward64/pen/aJZLKj

Comment: I'll be sure to sick around after I ask my question. Thanks for the tip T.J. Crowder!

Comment: @JasonHoward: To add details to your question, add them to the question itself, not just with links. Links rot, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. Instead, use Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). I've copied the pen into a snippet for you.

Comment: ok, thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with absolute positioning. Like this :

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.header {
  position: relative;
  background-color: grey;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
  min-height: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

.responsivecontainer {
  float: left;
  max-width: 20vw;
  min-height: 50px;
  display: flex;
}

.logo {
  margin: auto 0;
  z-index:10;
}

.clearfix:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.box {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header clearfix">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="responsivecontainer">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="http://www.bluebean.ca/logo1.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You will also need to set `z-index` value greater than that of box to keep box below elements in header.

Comment: Thanks for the information, but that doesn't really accomplish what I'm looking for. I want grey box to appear beside the logo. Not a rectangle.